# Logging Make/Ninja Warnings to a file

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gnu-make, ninja

The make/ninja-build output is missing the possibility to have a clear overview of warnings and other messages. I search a solution to log warnings, messages and other compiler information somehow to a file, and sort the information as well as remove dublicates.

Problems with the stdout which the compiler produces:

- Warnings and messages from header files are printed X-times instead of once
- the terminal coloring is not really helpful
- the terminal has a max line (back feed) where i can scroll back, the rest is lost

As for those who work with Eclipse CDT:
At the end of the build you get a list in the "Problems" window as follows:
FILENAME, LINE, WARNING /INFO

If there would be a solution to mirror this output into a file, this would be very helpful

Comment: On unix systems, you could do something like `make 2>&1 | tee myLogFile`, which does print everything to stdout as well as to `myLogFile`. Should be identical with `ninja`.

Comment: As @lubgr said, plus: When doing this in the cosole window, since you should start to resolve the compiler errors from top to bottom, simply pipe the output to `less` or `more`: `make 2>&1 | less`.

Comment: ok thank you i will have a look at it. but the translation for this is: reroute stdout, store and alalyse by hand? i was hoping there might be a happy-coder already facing this issue in the past :)